# How to add external dynamic link library dependency to bazel project

Tags: c++, dll, bazel, dynamic-linking

I've been trying to link a basic .dll to bazel project and I've been into some linker issues. The .dll I have is pretty simple, it's the example Microsoft provides:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// The Fibonacci recurrence relation describes a sequence F
// where F(n) is { n = 0, a
//               { n = 1, b
//               { n > 1, F(n-2) + F(n-1)
// for some initial integral values a and b.
// If the sequence is initialized F(0) = 1, F(1) = 1,
// then this relation produces the well-known Fibonacci
// sequence: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ...

// Initialize a Fibonacci relation sequence
// such that F(0) = a, F(1) = b.
// This function must be called before any other function.
extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API void fibonacci_init(
    const unsigned long long a, const unsigned long long b);

// Produce the next value in the sequence.
// Returns true on success and updates current value and index;
// false on overflow, leaves current value and index unchanged.
extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API bool fibonacci_next();

// Get the current value in the sequence.
extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API unsigned long long fibonacci_current();

// Get the position of the current value in the sequence.
extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API unsigned fibonacci_index();
```

And my BUILD file looks like:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")


#cc_import(
#    name = "MathLibrary",
#    hdrs = ["MathLibrary.h"],
#    shared_library = "libs/MathLibrary.dll",
#    interface_library = "libs/MathLibrary.lib",
#)
cc_library(
    name = "MathLibrary",
    srcs = ["libs/MathLibrary.dll"],
    hdrs = ["MathLibrary.h"],
)
cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["hello-world.cc"],
    deps = [":MathLibrary"],
)
```

The hello-world.cc contains the following:

```
  fibonacci_init(1, 1);
    // Write out the sequence values until overflow.
    do {
        std::cout << fibonacci_index() << ": "
            << fibonacci_current() << std::endl;
    } while (fibonacci_next());
    // Report count of values written before overflow.
    std::cout << fibonacci_index() + 1 <<
        " Fibonacci sequence values fit in an " <<
        "unsigned 64-bit integer." << std::endl;
```

I've been trying to use both cc_import and cc_library but neither work. For cc_library I get the following error:
`bazel-out\x64_windows-fastbuild\bin\main\hello-world.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals`

And for cc_import I can build successfully but when I try to run, nothing happens.